# UIDocumentPickerViewController .folder doesn’t give access to individual files

Tags: uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I followed the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories
but when trying to get access to each file inside the selected folder (tried iCloud and local folders) it always fails.

Did anything change which is not documented in that page? Do I have to set any other permission or capability? (I have iCloud Documents)
Thanks!!

If I specify a type of file on the Controller (say .audio) I can read selected files fine (selecting whole folders also fail)